# Share activity on Google Plus using asp dotnet

Tags: asp.net, google-plus

How can i post an interactive post on google+ stream?

I am trying to post some custom data on google stream from asp.net web application.

This is the code iam using.

this is .aspx page:
    
        Tell your friends

this is the script i am using:

```
var moment = {
        "name": "sample",
        "Description": "Hi sample post",
        "Thumbnail": "logo",
        "image": "http://prayati.com/Images/PrayatiLogo.jpg"
    };
    gapi.auth.init(signinCallback);
    function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
            gapi.interactivepost.render('inter', options);
            //gapi.interactivepost.render(moment, authResult['access_token'])
            gapi.interactivepost.go(moment)
            document.getElementById('myBtn').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
            alert(authResult['error']);
        }
    }
    var options = {
        contenturl: 'https://plus.google.com/pages/',
        contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
        clientid: '263087742134.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        prefilltext: 'Create your Google+ Page too!',
        calltoactionlabel: 'SHARE',
        calltoactionurl: 'http://plus.google.com/pages/create',
        calltoactiondeeplinkid: '/pages/create'
    };
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Google+ API?  https://developers.google.com/+/api/  What have you tried and in what way is it not working?

Comment: i am able to login but the share post box is not shown

Comment: Interactive posts are triggered by a client-side action. Can you show the code you're using that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The first and probably most important problem is that you have a domain mismatch between your `data-calltoactionurl` and your `data-contenturl`. These must be the same domain, see the [`data-contenturl` documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#button_attr_contenturl).

I believe that is your major problem, there are other problems in your example too:

You appear to be confusing two different features: app activities (aka moments) and interactive posts. Also, it looks like you are trying to do authentication, the interactive post button is also a sign-in button, notice its `data-callback` parameter. You wouldn't need to do a separate call to `gapi.auth.init()`

The most simple approach is to use the HTML button and remove the calls to gapi.interactivepost.* unless you have a dynamic application that needs to insert buttons with great control.

You didn't post the code for your JavaScript API include, ensure that it is loading the API script as `https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js`.

Here is a correct and simplified button:

```
<button class="g-interactivepost" 
  data-clientid="xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-contenturl="http://localhost:52022/Jaswanth"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-calltoactionlabel="INVITE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://localhost:52022/create"
  data-prefilltext="Best site EVER!"
  data-callback="signinCallback"
  data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
    Tell your friends
</button>
```